# Get snapshot with different resolution from 5 camera simultaneously without change the live video resolution?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, aforge

I used AForge.NET for some image processing task. I have 5 webcam and can see live of all these camera on WinForm. the max video resolution of these camera is HD. I do showing live of these camera with half of HD resolution, because the maximum bandwidth is reached and all of these camera cannot do live showing together.

my task is getting snapshot from all these camera simultaneity with HD resolution. Is there any technique that I can change the resolution just for taking snapshot without resting the resolution of camera for live video?

The following code on Snapshot button not works:

```
        videoSource1.DesiredFrameSize = new Size(4096, 2160);
        videoSourcePlayer1.VideoSource = videoSource1;
        
        img = videoSourcePlayer1.GetCurrentVideoFrame();
        dest = "d:\\file1.png";
        img.Save(dest);
```

Comment: so why not just resizing the image?

Comment: I want to capture a HD image @HesamFaridmehr

Comment: I mean initialize videoSource with max resolution then on view time resize the image and then draw image

Comment: With Max resolution we cannot offer 5 Live camera with one system. the specific system is limited. @HesamFaridmehr

Comment: I'm not telling that draw with max resolution just grab max resolution from webcams

Comment: How I can do this? @HesamFaridmehr

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think it's better to use Accord.Net instead of Aforge.Net

Second you should use `VideoCaptureDevice` to capture video from webcams code will be like

```
videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(moniker);
videoCaptureDevice.VideoResolution = videoCaptureDevice.VideoCapabilities.OrderByDescending(vc => vc.FrameSize.Width).First();
videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;

videoCaptureDevice.Start();
```

In `VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame` you can draw on panel with code like

```
lastFrame?.Dispose();
lastFrame = frame.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height), frame.PixelFormat);

var resizedFrame = new ResizeNearestNeighbor(width, height).Apply(lastFrame);
panelGraphics.DrawImage(resizedFrame, 0, 0);
resizedFrame.Dispose();
```

and you can use lastFrame if user wants a snapshot

Comment: we have 5 camera with 300*600 resolution and live output. OK?  I define a button that take screenshot when clicked. which part is defined in this button?

Comment: In button click event you will use lastFrame object and save it somewhere

Comment: you start the camera? I means live with maximum resolution yes?

Comment: Where is videocapturedevice_newframe? this is error.

Comment: videoSource1 = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
            videoSource1.DesiredFrameRate = 30;

            videoSourcePlayer1.VideoSource = videoSource1;

Comment: where of this code I should insert "videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;"

Comment: VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame is call back to NewFrame event

Comment: what is lastFrame definition?